# Create particular node order for graph coloring problem

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, graph-coloring

I struggle with the algorithm to create the order in which I will color a graph.
Let's consider the following graph:

[image: Network graph]

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (1, 5), (5, 6), (6, 10), 
         (6, 7), (4, 7), (3, 8), (7, 8), (8, 9), (8, 11)]

# Create the graph
G = nx.Graph()
# Add edges
G.add_edges_from(edges)
# Plot
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_size = 16)
plt.show()
```

I want to have multiple starting point, called `initial_nodes` and to create the order around the adjacent nodes. For the graph above, let's consider the starting nodes as the node `2` and `7`.

The order would be:

```
# Step 1: - Initial nodes
order = [2, 7]
# Step 2: - Nodes adjacent to the initial nodes
order = [2, 7, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8]
# Step 3: - Nodes adjacent to the nodes added in the previous step
# If they are not already present in the order...
order = [2, 7, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 10, 9, 11]
```

I feel like a recursive approach should work nice, but I can't figure how to write it down. Any idea?

**EDIT:** All the problem described a bit [further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336916/graph-coloring-problem-select-alternative-value-for-each-node).

Current algorithm to create the order:

```
def create_node_order(graph, initial_nodes):
    """
    Create the node order.
    """
    # Initialization
    order = initial_nodes
    next_nodes = list()

    for node in initial_nodes:
        for adj_node in graph.adj[node].keys():
            if adj_node not in order:
                order.append(adj_node)
                next_nodes.append(adj_node)

    while len(next_nodes) != 0:

        for node in next_nodes:
            for adj_node in graph.adj[node].keys():
                if adj_node not in order:
                    order.append(adj_node)
                    next_nodes.append(adj_node)

            next_nodes.remove(node)

    return order
```

Comment: Is the goal to arrive at any coloring or is it required to find a minimal coloring? I know of no proof that this approach would yield an optimal coloring. Usually the order of coloring is very much not trivial and some approaches I know require backtracking, meaning that "order" is meaningless with them.

Comment: @EtienneOtt I am no expert in graph theory... from what I read, there is no algorithm to arrive efficiently (less than exponential time) to an optimal coloring. I don't know exactly yet what backtracking is. From what I saw, it is about going down a path, and going back up to correct the colors in order to achieve a better global coloring. At the moment, I do not want to use backtracking, and I'd like to try a greedy approach. I will not describe the entire problem, but the order I describe above is chosen wisely based on my data and the coloring I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @EtienneOtt I just can't figure out an algorithm to create this order efficiently... and although I feel like a recursive approach is the right choice, I can' tfigure out how to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

Note that is was not a requirement, or even proven to be possible, to result in an optimal coloring given the approach of iterating over "circles" "radiating" out from some start nodes. Given my understand of the algorithm described and what the requirements are, I would use something like this:

Pseudocode:

```
// no need for more than four colors IFF the algorithm is optimal and the graph is planar, otherwise extend
colors = [red, blue, green, yellow]
// initialize
graph = SomeSuitableDataStructure(data)
queue = [graph(2), graph(7)] // starting nodes
for node in graph.nodes:
    node.visited = False
    node.color = Undefined

while not queue.empty():
    node = queue.pop()
    node.visited = True
    node.color = first_color_not_in([n.color for n in node.neighbors()])
    for neighbor in node.neighbors():
        if not neighbor.visited: queue.push_back(neighbor)
```

Implementing `first_color_not_in()` and handling the `Undefined` color is left as an excercise to the reader.

Comment: This is doing the coloring and not just the order. I was simply looking in a way to produce the order in a more efficient way that the code I added in the Edit. My problem is actually a bit different. Each node has a list of available alternative values, and the goal is to select one for each node in such a way that the deviation between close-by nodes (linked) is minimized. On the contrary of a coloring problem, the goal is to have connected nodes with the same, or with the closest possible color... That's why the "circles" approach makes sense and that's why I was looking only for the order

Comment: Anyway, indeed, with a pure coloring problem, your approach is great and indeed, the maximum number of required colors is d+1 with d the degree.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure about the difference between the order of iteration for constructing a queue and the order of coloring, because with most algorithms it is the same, or more precisely, it is the crux of the problem and finding one is finding the other.

Comment: And by the way, it's not maxed 4 colors if the algorithm is optimal. It's rather that the greedy algorithm will in worst case need 4 colors, depending on the order in which the coloring is performed.

Comment: And I am not sure what you mean by order of the queue, since both in your algorithm, and on the one I am writing, the order of the queue is the order in which the nodes are colored.

Comment: I just realized, and noted in my answer, that the Four-Color-Theorem only holds for planar graphs. The example graph happens to be planar, but the algorithm doesn't care. So yes, the necessary number of colors depends on the graph in question.

Comment: Oh thanks! I actually did not know about that theorem yet! I thought about another one using the maximum degree.